# beautifulsoup qpython ERROR

Tags: beautifulsoup, qpython

I'm working on a scraping project using BeautifulSoup in qPython.

Here is some code

```
    import BeautifulSoup
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as Soup
    import requests
    import re

    r = requests.get(".....")

    soup = Soup(r.text)

    data  = soup.find_all("script")[12].string
```

Here is error at last line of above code sample

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I have followed guidelines of package installation and importing from other posts from stackoverflow.
THANK YOU

Comment: This means that `soup.find_all("script")` is returning `None`. Try printing it first.

Comment: The script is working on PC but I wished to have it on mobile.

Comment: object soup has all the r.text but it is not returning anything. Problem is with soup.find_all("script") only.

Comment: soup.find("script") is returning first script tag

Comment: soup.findAll('script') is working. :D . New Errors to Solve though... Thanks

Comment: Didn't see that it's bs3

Answer (score 0):

This means that `soup.find_all("script")` is returning `None`

**Try printing it first.**